# Spring websocket and spring security without executor on clientInboundChannel

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-websocket

We are using spring-websocket, and have been overriding the Bean [AbstractMessageBrokerConfiguration#clientInboundChannel()](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-messaging/src/main/java/org/springframework/messaging/simp/config/AbstractMessageBrokerConfiguration.java#L119) so that the channel is created without an Executor. The reason for this is that we have seen that it leads to response times being generally lower. 
This have been working fine so far, but when trying to add spring-security to the websocket it does not work. It will not be fully configured and we have not managed to find a workaround.

Is there some way to use spring-websocket with spring-security and at the same time send messages on the callers thread?

This is how we override the bean:

```
@Bean
public AbstractSubscribableChannel clientInboundChannel() {
    ExecutorSubscribableChannel channel = new ExecutorSubscribableChannel();
    ChannelRegistration registration = new ChannelRegistration();
    configureClientInboundChannel(registration);
    channel.addInterceptor(channelInterceptor);
    channel.addInterceptor(new ImmutableMessageChannelInterceptor());
    return channel;
}
```